# Count Distinct field with group by

Tags: mysql

Here I ma trying to do

```
SELECT b.sponso , b.source_id , Count(Distinct b.source_id) As nb_part
FROM buzzes b 
WHERE b.type = 3 AND b.sponso_id != 0
GROUP BY b.source_id , b.sponso
```

And the output :

```
+------------+--------------+--------+
| Sponso     | source_id   | nb_part | 
+------------+--------------+--------+
| A          | 954711      | 1       | 
| A          | 587741      | 1       | 
| B          | 321447      | 1       | 
| B          | 350         | 1       |
+------------+--------------+--------+
```

And what I am expected to have

```
+------------+--------------+--------+
| Sponso     | source_id   | nb_part | 
+------------+--------------+--------+
| A          | 954711      | 2       | 
| B          | 321447      | 2       | 
+------------+--------------+--------+
```

I wanted to count the sum of nb_part and group by Sponso but I am stuck with my query

Comment: There are 4 different values for `source_id` and `GROUP BY source_id` produces 4 different groups for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want the maximum `source_id` and the number of different `source_id` per `sponso`. "Per sponso" translates to `GROUP BY sponso` in SQL.

```
SELECT sponso, MAX(source_id) AS source_id, COUNT(DISTINCT source_id) AS nb_part
FROM buzzes
WHERE type = 3 AND sponso_id != 0
GROUP BY sponso
ORDER BY sponso;
```

Or maybe you want to aggregate over your query:

```
SELECT sponso, MAX(source_id) AS source_id, SUM(nb_part) AS nb_part
FROM
(
  SELECT b.sponso , b.source_id , Count(Distinct b.source_id) As nb_part
  FROM buzzes b 
  WHERE b.type = 3 AND b.sponso_id != 0
  GROUP BY b.source_id , b.sponso 
)
GROUP BY sponso
ORDER BY sponso;
```